# Install software from source

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, makefile, apt

I am trying to install postgresql10 in ubuntu 16.

Already successfully tried with apt repo.(using apt-get)

My intention is to install postgresql10 in ubuntu 16 and prevent it from apt-upgrade(using mark-hold)

But this will cause upgrade in dependencies even if we hold postgresql package.So I am thinking to go for make install postgresql.

If i do make install postgresql will apt-upgrade update postgresql and dependencies?.If i follow this approach am i safe from apt-update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hold the version of `postgresql`, your package management should know that it needs certain versions of the dependencies. It may update the dependencies as long as the version requirements are met. It will report problems if it would need to update some dependencies which are locked to older versions by the `postgresql` package.

If you build and install `postgresql-10` from source, your `apt` will of course not update this local installation.

To build it you will probably need some development libraries which refer to the corresponding system libraries. Probably it will be built with dynamically linked libraries, so `apt` may later update the dependencies (i.e. the libraries needed by `postgresql` and corresponding development libraries).

This can be even more problematic because your `apt` does not know that you locally installed a version of `postgresql` that may depend on specific versions of the dependencies.

The only way to prevent `apt` from updating anything related to `postgresql` would be if its build procedure allows to link all libraries statically.

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall all PostgreSQL software installed with the package manager, the PostgreSQL you install from source will not be upgraded automatically.

However, the software that PostgreSQL depends on will be upgraded. This should not be a problem if Ubuntu has good package management.

Preventing PostgreSQL from being updated is a very bad idea.